# Popular coluna com id criado + data/hora

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

Eu tenho uma coluna com o nome "code". É possível preencher a mesma usando o mesmo método que insere o formulário? Se sim, como posso implementar isso no meu código.

**Método que recebe o formulário e insere no banco.**

```
    public function insert(ManifestationFormRequest $request)
{

    //armazena form em dataForm
    $dataForm = $request->except('_token');

    //Insere Formulário no Banco
    $insert = $this->manifestation->insert($dataForm);

    //verifica se existe arquivo e se é válido
    if($request->hasFile('upload') && $request->file('upload')->isValid())
    {
        //Define default para variavel que vai conter nome do arquivo.
        $fileName = null;

        //Define nome aleatorio baseado no timestamp atual.
        $name = uniqid(date('dmYHis'));

        //Pega extensao do arquivo original e armazena em $ext.
        $ext = $request->upload->getClientOriginalExtension();

        //Define nome do arquivo + extensão.
        $fileName = "{$name}.{$ext}";

        //Armazena arquivo em Storage/app/uploads e renomeia.
        $upload = $request->upload->storeAs('uploads', $fileName);
    }

    Alert::success('Enviado...', 'Obrigado pela sua contribuição');
    return redirect()->route('index');
}
```

**Migrate**

```
Schema::create('manifestations', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('code', 64)->nullable();
        $table->string('name', 64);
        $table->string('email', 100);
        $table->string('rg', 20)->nullable();
        $table->string('cpf', 14)->nullable();
        $table->string('address', 150);
        $table->string('cep', 10);
        $table->string('city', 36);
        $table->string('state', 8);
        $table->string('phone', 16);
        $table->string('fax', 16)->nullable();
        $table->integer('FK_cat_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('upload')->nullable();
        $table->string('manifestation', 800);
        $table->enum('response', [
                                    'Email',
                                    'Telefone',
                                    'Fax',
                                    'Não Informado'
                                ]);
        $table->timestamps();
```

Comment: Coluna code onde?

Comment: Opa! Atualizado com minha migrate.

Comment: $dataForm['code'] ='valor' isso resolve se for um preenchimento manual

Comment: `$code = hexdec(uniqid());` me retorna um valor decimal com 13 dígitos. Quero a ID recém criada concatenando com `$code` inserida no campo code do mesmo registro. ps: desculpe se não fui bem claro rs

Comment: Pega o resultado do insert e atribua o valor pra code do jeito que vc quiser e chame o metodo save(). Exemplo: $insert->code = $code; $insert->save();

Comment: O que eu quero juntar é o `increments('id');` com  `$code` e colocar o resultado no campo code ta tabela.

Comment: Você precisa dar uma lida na documentação, faça isso... criei um exemplo minimo em resposta dá uma olhada

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo esforço @VirgilioNovic. Eu tenho lido, porém não tenho conseguido subtrair muito bem o que preciso. Vou analisar sua resposta e fazer a implementação. Novamente meu obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelos comentários e com uma opção simples pode fazer da seguinte forma depois desse código logo abaixo acrescente:

```
//Insere Formulário no Banco
$insert = $this->manifestation->insert($dataForm);
if ($insert) // se for inserido com êxito você já pode utilizar no modo atualização
{
    //Passa o valor ao campo code
    $insert->code = hexdec(uniqid()).$insert->id;
    //Salve a alteração
    $insert->save();
}
//Continue o código normalmente
```

Existe também um outra opção que é fazer isso com [Observes que na sua documentação explica](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#observers) que pode ser utilizado nos seguintes eventos:

- *Retrieved*
- *Creating* e *Created*
- *Updating* e *Updated*
- *Saving* e *Saved*
- *Deleting* e *Deleted*
- *Restoring* e *Restored*

que pela terminação `ing` o evento ainda não ocorreu, e `ted` que o evento já ocorreu e pode ser feito outros modificações, que no seu caso o evento correspondente é `created`, ou seja, já criou o registro, então tem acesso ao `id` gerado pelo banco.

Dentro da pasta `app` crie uma pasta com o nome de `Observers` e dentro dessa pasta crie um arquivo da seguinte forma:

```
<?php namespace App\Observers;

use App\Manifestation; // model

class Manifestation
{
    public function created(Manifestation $manifestation)
    {
        $manifestation->code = hexdec(uniqid()).$manifestation->id;
        $manifestation->save();
    }
}
```

depois entre no arquivo `app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php` e adicione no método `boot` o `observer` que foi criado:

```
<?php namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\Manifestation;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        Manifestation::observe(ManifestationObserver::class);
    }
}
```

após isso, todas as vezes que for inserido um registro no evento de executa essa modificação e altera o valor de código.

Você só pode pegar o `id` inserido logo após ele for gerado, por isso tem que ser no modo de edição desse registro.

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [Laravel - Observers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#observers)
- [Como aliviar seus controllers com os eventos do Eloquent no Laravel](https://www.treinaweb.com.br/blog/como-aliviar-seus-controllers-com-os-eventos-eloquent-no-laravel/)
- [Using Laravel Model Observers](https://tutsforweb.com/laravel-model-observers-tutorial/)

Comment: Deu certo aqui, valew!

Answer (score -2):

Antes de tudo você pode dar um merge na request adicionando o campo.

```
$request->merge(['code' => $valor_que_quiser]);
$dataForm = $request->except('_token');
...
```

Dá um dd($request->all()) depois do merge e verá que o code fará parte dos dados do form.

At-te;